# Prove that $f(y)-f(x)=\langle\nabla f(a),y-x\rangle+r(x,y)$, where $|r(x,y)|<\epsilon|x-y|$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}^m$ be an open set and consider the $C^1$ function $f:U\to\Bbb R$. Given $a\in U$ and $\epsilon>0$, prove that exist $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in U, |x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$ implies $f(x)-f(y)=\langle\nabla f(a),y-x\rangle+r(x,y)$, where $|r(x,y)|<\epsilon|x-y|$.

I had a simple idea but couldn't finish the problem.

Using the fact that $f$ is differentiable on $a$ we have $f(x)=f(a)+\langle\nabla f(a),x-a\rangle+r_1(x)$ and $f(y)=f(a)+\langle\nabla f(a),y-a\rangle+r_2(y)$. Subtracting both equations we get the equation $$f(y)-f(x)=\langle\nabla f(a),y-x\rangle+r(x,y)$$
Where $r(x,y)=r_2(y)-r_1(x)=f(y)-f(x)+\langle\nabla f(a),x-y\rangle$. Using Cauchy-Schwarz, $$|r(x,y)|\leq|f(x)-f(y)|+|\nabla f(a)||x-y|$$
So a nice idea is using Mean Value Theorem, but I can't guarantee that the segment $[x,y]$ is included on $U$. So, how can I conclude the final inequality ?

Comment: Do you mean "...such that for all $x,y\in U$, $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<\delta$ implies..." ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $U$ is open, for $\delta$ small enough the ball of radius $\delta$ and center $a$ is a subset of $U$. It is convex, so you have $[x,y]\subset U$ automatically. I haven't checked that this plus the MVT gives a full answer to your question